Apply string. join on Dictionary<string, List<int>>
I have situation where i have a dictionary of type Dictionary<string, List<int>> . I would like to apply sting.Join to it, I would like to have data displayed like:
"abc1:1,2,3,4,abc2:1,3,8,abc3:3,1,7" 

what i tried is this :
$"{string.Join(", ", iformation.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Key + ": " + string.Join(",", x.Value.ToArray())))}";

The output was :
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]]:

can somebody help me with what i want to achieve ?

Your example expected-result looks like JSON - why not use a JSON serializer instead? Using String.Join means you need to be careful you don't generate invalid JSON. (e.g. what happens if any of your dictionary .Key values contains quotes or spaces?)

I ran your code, and it doesn't produce the output you claim it does. It's not quite what you want, (no [ or ], and some extra spaces), but it's not far off

no they will always contain integers

Voting to close as it isn't possible to reproduce the issue you're seeing. Example.

Your string.Join works fine. Where is your code for setting up iformation and how do you print the output?

No repro, even in .NET 5. There's no need for string interpolation either, String.Join already returns a string. No need for ToArray() either. The code is redundant but works. .NET 5 reached End-Of-Life in May 2022, over 2 years ago. Even .NET 6, the oldest LTS version, reached EOL in November 2024.

The only way to get System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary... is to call iFormation.ToString or use $"{iformation}". I suspect the actual code is so complicated it ends up serializing the wrong thing.

Output like yours happens, when you invoke ToString method on collections (dictionary in your case). Below you can find correct code and compare to it:
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
{
    ["abc1"] = [1,2,3,4],
    ["abc3"] = [3,1,7],
    ["abc2"] = [1,3,8],
};

var result = string.Join(
    ", ", 
    dict
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
        .Select(x => $"{x.Key}:{string.Join(",", x.Value)}"));

Here you can find working example.

Short version:
var s = string.Join(',',
    from row in data
    orderby row.Key
    select row.Key + ":" + string.Join(',', row.Value));
Console.WriteLine(s);

However, all of the Join / Concat options here would be "pretty" but inefficient, in that it would create multiple intermediate values - specifically, for each key, additionally:

a string of the comma-separated values, i.e. "1,2,3,4"
a string of that string composed with the key, i.e. "abc1:1,2,3,4"

which then need to be collected.
IMO, just do it manually:
Dictionary<string, List<int>> data = new()
{
    ["abc1"] = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ["abc2"] = [1, 3, 8],
    ["abc3"] = [3, 1, 7],
};

// TODO: possible check for `data.Count == 0`, i.e. `return "";`
var sb = new StringBuilder();
bool firstKey = true;
foreach (var (key, list) in data) // possible OrderBy(x => x.Key) here
{
    if (firstKey)
    {
        firstKey = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(',');
    }
    sb.Append(key).Append(':');
    bool firstVal = true;
    foreach (var val in list)
    {
        if (firstVal)
        {
            firstVal = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(',');
        }
        sb.Append(val);
    }
}
var s = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s);

Also note that dictionaries are by nature unordered, so the keys might not appear in the order you expect; the values within each key, however, will remain ordered.
